# How come my non-ATS supporting app is working on iOS9?

Tags: ios, ios9

I'm running the beta version of iOS 9 on my phone.
I downloaded my app from the App Store and it works.
When I install it from Xcode it doesn't work (since it is not supporting ATS).

How can that be?

Answer (score 0):

When introducing features in new iOS versions Apple often checks for the link time or SDK version of the app.

Applying new rules only to apps that are linked to iOS SDK 9 for example, they can enforce the rule on new builds, where the developer should be aware of the rule. Old apps are left alone and keep working as before.

Answer (score 0):

The version from the App Store is likely linked against an earlier SDK version. Apple determines behavior for some things like UI and, AFAIK, ATS, by looking at the linked SDK version.

Apple notices that App Store version is linked against an SDK version that doesn't know about ATS and enables legacy support. But your version compiled in Xcode is linked against a SDK version that *does* know about ATS and Apple therefor enforces the rules.